# XCode doesn't run and doesn't show output

Tags: swift, xcode

I created a simple playground in Xcode 12. When I run below code, nothing shows in the console.

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "Hello, playground"
print(greeting)
```

This is the default playground, I just printed the variable. There're no errors nor warnings. It was working 2 days ago, but suddenly it stopped outputting.

I also activated console from **file > View > Debug Area > Activate Console**.

Can you help me fix it? thank you in advance.

Edit:
Added Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Did u check the usual suspects (delete derived data, restart Xcode)?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my computer, restarted Xcode, and deleted derived data. NO LUCK YET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same issue. If I launch Xcode using rosetta it doesn't show anything, but once I switch off rosetta and it works perfectly.
Open Get Info on Xcode.app and unchecked "Open using Rosetta". then Playgrounds springs into life.

[image: Xcode get info unchecked open using rosetta]

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's a pleasure to help.